# PageNotFoundError(404) even though it is specified in the url

Tags: python, http-status-code-404

I am currently making a blog but when I was adding a like button an error struck. How do I fix it. The traceback gives a 404 even though it is specified in my urls.

Error area/Traceback:

Page not found (404)
No Post matches the given query.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/20
Raised by:  myblog.views.LikeView
Using the URLconf defined in ablog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
[name='home']
article/<int:pk> [name='article-detail']
add_post/ [name='add_post']
add_category/ [name='add_category']
article/edit/<int:pk> [name='update_post']
article/edit/<int:pk>/remove [name='delete_post']
category/<str:cats>/ [name='category']
category-list/ [name='category-list']
like/<int:pk> [name='like_post']
The current path, like/20, matched the last one.
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post.id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
#from . import views
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView, CategoryListView, LikeView

path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='like_post'),
```

article_details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title_tag }}{% endblock %}




<style>
    button {
        display:block;
        margin:0.5em;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<small>By: {{ post.author.first_name }} 
    {{ post.author.last_name }} - 
    {{ post.post_date }} 

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.id == post.author.id %}

        <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit) </a>

        <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>
        {% elif user.id == 1 %}

            - <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit)</a>

            <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>

        {% endif %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}

</small><br/>
<hr>
<br/>
{{ post.body| safe }}


<br/><br/>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>

    <br/><br/>
    <hr>
    <br/>
    <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button>
    </form>



{% endblock %}
```

models.py
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post'

Also I have cut some area which are not relevant to the question. If I have missed any file please do ask in the add comments section.

Comment: Are you getting the error after clicking the Like button ? @Kaushik

Comment: @Ram Yes. I am getting an error as soon as I click the button. Also I am getting this at the bottom of the traceback. "You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page."

Comment: Where are you getting ```post.id``` from ? This line: ```post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post.id'))``` in your ```LikeView```

Comment: I have imported them. I also have other views underneath this.

Comment: I am asking from where are you getting that ```post.id``` ?

Comment: @ Ram I am getting them from my models.py. As I have imported them to views.py.

Comment: Could you post complete code of ```article_details.html``` ?

Comment: sure absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the urls. It is actually written in the Exception description - "No Post matches the given query". There is no Posts record in your database with the given id.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my views.py to this and worked.

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```